# Geometric reason why even unimodular positive definite lattices exist only in dimensions divisible by $8$

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, modular-forms, integer-lattices

It is a well-known fact that even unimodular rank $n$ lattices $L\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ only exist if $8\vert n$.

The only proof of this that I know (in the book "Elliptic functions and modular forms" by Koecher/Krieg) is rather ingenious and uses the modularity of the associated theta function $$\Theta(\tau,L)=\sum_{\gamma\in L}e^{i\pi\Vert \gamma\Vert^2}$$ to conclude that 
$$\Theta(i,L)=e^{\frac{i\pi n}{4}}\Theta(i,L)$$
and hence $8\vert n$.

While it is quite natural to associate a theta function to a lattice, it seems to me that there has to be a deeper, somehow "purely geometric reason" for this phenomenon (i.e. the condition on the dimension) which does not use the theory of modular forms.

So my question is the following:

What is the "geometric" reason why even unimodular positive definite lattices exist only in dimensions divisble by $8$?

(I am aware that the term "geometric" is not well-defined and can be interpreted broadly: feel free to do so)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of relying on the theory of modular forms for the proof, one can also use the methods from "geometry of numbers". Such a proof can be found, for example, in Serre's book *A course in Arithmetic*, on page $53$, Theorem $2$. Of course, the geometry of numbers might not give you an "geometric" reason in the sense you are looking for. I am not sure, that a "pure geometric argument" suffices.

Perhaps it is helpful to view the more general picture.
Consider *unimodular symmetric bilinear modules*, which are free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules endowed with an integral symmetric bilinear form of discriminant $\pm 1$. As a real form it has signature $(r,s)$. Then one can show 
with "geometric" methods that the following is true:

*Proposition:* The signature $(r,s)$ of an even unimodular symmetric bilinear module satisfies the congruence $r\equiv s\bmod 8$.

For even unimodular lattices of rank $r$ we obtain $r\equiv 0\bmod 8$. For a proof, see Serre, as above.

Comment: Just noticed this, a guy asked this today but then deleted a few minutes later. There is a proof (actually homework exercise with hints) in Rational Quadratic Forms by Cassels; chapter 9, exercise 10, pages 163-164 in my paperback edition http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html   deleted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606725/a-unimodular-even-positive-square-matrix-must-have-dimension-divisible-by-8 I left some comments at his most recent non-deleted question.